# Swift - separate views have subviews that are sharing the same memory?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, memory, uicollectionview

new to swift. I have a nested CollectionView from one viewcontroller. The main viewcontroller has 7 collectionviewcell ("Level1Cell" in the code below). Each time I click a button or trigger an event, I want the collectionView to reload with the new data.

```
func eventHandler() {
// updates data
myCollectionView.reloadData()

}
```

Then, after it calls reload, it will call the reload again on each of the  the nested CollectionViewCell.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Level1Cell", for: indexPath) as! Level1Cell
    cell.appsCollectionView.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

The problem is, let say I want to, for the first cell, set a particular row some text.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {                
   if(self.index == 0  && indexPath.row == 30){
        rightCell.textLabel.text = "asdasd"
    }
```

The fourth "Level1Cell" cell somehow has its label set also at the 30th row, but not the second and third. After stepping through the debugger, I realize that the cells, after reloading, the fourth cell "Level1Cell" is set to have the the same memory address as the first cell ( why does reload do this - shouldn't it allocate a new memory for each "Level1Cell"? - how can I get around this). Also, should I not use reload to update the data in the view and nested view of those from the view controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIcollectionview` will reuse cells. You must provide needed data for row in method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

Or just clear previous data at cell.

Comment: what do you mean by provide data. I set the rightCell.textLabel.text. In the "leve1Cell" case, I also did cell.data = xyz, but did not put it in here.

Comment: I mean, If your not set new or not remove old label in cell at some indexpath they will contain old data

Comment: so after stepping through my debugger, it's the Level1Cell that has the same memory addresses. SHould dequeue allocate new memory each time. But calling reload would reuse the memory of preivous cells?

Comment: Don't memory. UICollectionView all time use previous cell. Even before reloaddata.